# MySQL - Sort table efficiently when querying by another attribute

Tags: mysql, sql, query-performance

On this JS fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4c7bc0/7

```
CREATE TABLE big_table(id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                       user_id INTEGER NOT NULL);
```

The second query

```
SELECT * FROM big_table WHERE user_id IN ( 1, 100, 1000 )
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Is planned as: Using where; Using index; Using filesort

When big_table contains tens of millions of rows, the filesort kills the performance.

How do I ORDER BY faster?

Answer (score 1):

For this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM big_table
WHERE user_id IN ( 1, 100, 1000 )
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

You cannot easily get rid of the work for the `ORDER BY` (there is one possible way, see below).  Most importantly, you need an index on `big_table(user_id)`:

```
 CREATE INDEX idx_bigtable_userid ON big_table(user_id);
```

If there are only a few dozen or hundreds of rows that match, then this should be fine.

Another possibility is to rewrite the query, and use an index on:

```
 CREATE INDEX idx_bigtable_userid ON big_table(user_id, id);
```

I should start by saying that I'm not 100% sure that this approach will work because of the `DESC` on id.  But, the following query should use the index:

```
SELECT *
FROM big_table
WHERE user_id = 1
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

So you can do:

```
SELECT *
FROM ((SELECT t.*
       FROM big_table t
       WHERE t.user_id = 1
       ORDER BY id DESC
       LIMIT 10
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT t.*
       FROM big_table t
       WHERE t.user_id = 100
       ORDER BY id DESC
       LIMIT 10
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT t.*
       FROM big_table t
       WHERE t.user_id = 1000
       ORDER BY id DESC
       LIMIT 10
      ) 
     ) t
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: That will probably work for this example, but in real life, there can be about 1000 user_id-s coming from a subquery (or a join originally before I've started to try to optimize that)

Comment: The two suggested indexes are identical _if_ the table is `ENGINE=InnoDB`.  This is because InnoDB appends the PK columns to each secondary index.

Comment: With more than one `user_id` in the `IN`, the index _cannot_ be used to avoid a sort -- this is because the index entries are not in `id` order.  However, `ORDER BY user_id, id DESC` would (I think) avoid the sort.

Comment: As for `DESC` in the `ORDER BY`, as long as the sequence of rows in the index exactly match the desired `ORDER`, the `SELECT` can scan forward (`ASC`) or backward (`DESC`).  This implies that `ORDER BY a DESC, b DESC` can use `INDEX(a,b)`, but `ORDER BY a DESC, b ASC` must sort (until 8.0, when `DESC` is honored in `INDEX`).

Comment: The `UNION` may be faster.  However, it can be simplified:  `( SELECT ... ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10 ) UNION ALL ( SELECT ... ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10 ) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10;` -- no need for the outer `SELECT`; a `UNION` can have its own `ORDER BY..LIMIT`.

Comment: Assuming there really are only 2 columns in the table (which I suspect is not the case), both suggested indexes are at least 'covering'.